# Que es "NaN" y porque aparece?

Tags: java

Estaba trabajando con factoriales, puse 1000! y me retorno NaN.
me pueden explicar porque me retorna NaN
(creo que podría ser por los bits)

Comment: Dependerá de donde se mostró . sin su código no podríamos saberlo. por favor añadir el código empleando el enlace [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/106350/edit)

Comment: Favor de especiicar que siugnifica 1000! si es un factorial lo que deseas o si lo enviaste como una cadena. De igual manera si tuvieras el código sería de mucha ayuda paa resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

El factorial de 1000 es un número de 2568 cifras que no entra entra en un long de Java cuyo valor máximo es 
9,223,372,036,854,775,807 o sea 19 cifras.
El resultado NaN significa Not a Number, representa un overflow en el cálculo.
Si realmente necesitas calcular el factorial de números grandes hay algoritmos basados en arrays de enteros para eso.